# Агоритм поиска частичного совпадения изображений по RGB на Java

Tags: java, алгоритм

Здравствуте. Столкнулся с задачей поиска координат малого изображеня в большом по RGB. Но не точного, а частичного. Тоесть метод должен принимать еще и процент совпадения, при котором совпадение можно считать достаточным.

Идея была в том чтобы взять искомое изображение как маску, и двигаться с ней по основному изображению, вхождение в которое мы ищем. 
В том случае если, найдено совпадающее колличество пикселей больше чем пороговое значение, то результат записывается в мапу с возможными ответами. А в качестве конечного результата используется то зачение, которое набрало большее колличество процентов совпадения.

Предпринял такую попытку:

```
public static Point findSubImg(final int percentage, final BufferedImage subImage, final BufferedImage fullImage) {
    if (percentage < 1 || percentage > 100) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("@arg int percents should be from 1 to 100");
    }

    final Map<Integer, Point> results = new HashMap<>();
    results.put(-1, new Point());

    int pixPercentage = (int) (((float)(subImage.getHeight() * subImage.getWidth())) * ((float) percentage / 100F));

    int lastMaxEqPix = 0, counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= fullImage.getWidth() - subImage.getWidth(); i++) {
        checkSubImage:
        for (int j = 0; j <= fullImage.getHeight() - subImage.getHeight(); j++) {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < subImage.getWidth(); ii++) {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < subImage.getHeight(); jj++) {
                    if (subImage.getRGB(ii, jj) == fullImage.getRGB(i + ii, j + jj)) {
                        counter++;
                        lastMaxEqPix = counter;
                    } else {
                        if (counter > lastMaxEqPix && counter > pixPercentage) {
                            lastMaxEqPix = counter;
                            results.put(lastMaxEqPix, new Point(i + subImage.getWidth() / 2, j + subImage.getHeight() / 2));
                        }
                        continue checkSubImage;
                    }
                }
            }
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

    return results.get(Collections.max(results.keySet()));
}
```

Но что-то идет не так, и не один вариант совпадения не проходит порога вхождения даже с теми тестовыми данными, где заведомо извесно что такое вхождение есть.

Помогите пожалуйста довести этот алгоритм до рабочего состояния, или возможно кто-то предложит аналог решающий эту же задачу. Буду очень признателен за помощь.